# mac: java controller panel not update my terminal java version

Tags: java

Java Control Panel remind me to update my Java to 1.8.0 update 181.

After install the recommended version, java control panel says the system has the latest version now (update 181).

But when I run command java -version on my terminal. The system tell me that still install the 171 version of java. And below '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/' directory, there is no 181 version folder of java.

What does Java Control panel do?

Comment: not sure how mac works, but if there is an equilavent of environment variables on mac, you can look into those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, and possibly yours, it's due to the fact that I'd installed the JDK, and so this is the version that is picked up in the terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

There are two other executables installed under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`:

```
$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

However, there remains one more `java` executable, under `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`:

```
$ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

I believe this is the one that the control panel maintains, and installing the latest version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html has updated the default terminal version for me.